# Basic hello world program fails to build in visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

I am just now learning C++ at school and was told to download visual studio for an ide. I made a simple hello world program just to see if it was working and it fails to build. it gives me 417 errors, saying things like "cannot open source file "errno.h" and several other source files. I just downloaded it so I don't know how it could be broken so badly. Im quite new to coding so my knowledge is very limited. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks